# add html and script into wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to plugin development in wordpress.

I want to add just a simple html code to wp_footer using action hook I just learned from wordpress codex.

```
<?php
        /* 
        Plugin Name: test
        Plugin URI: http://mysite.com
        Description: test
        Version: 1.0 
        Author: me
        Author URI: http://mysite.com
        */  

    function addbar(){
    echo '<div id="cbar">';
    echo '</div>';
    }

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ){
       add_action('wp_footer','addbar');
    } else {
    }
?>
```

This code does not works , it crashes my site.

Comment: show me some more code. what did you mean crash?

Comment: my whole site becomes blank.

Comment: did you check the html source?

Comment: Where exactly are you adding this plugin?

Comment: i am assuming that site gone white is not crashing but there is error in the script. Please check the error log. You might find some help there.

Comment: I want to add `<div id="cbar"></div>` to every page in my wordpress except the admin page. when i activate this plugin , my site just went blank including the admin panel. so I have to remove it. is it my syntax error?

Comment: Hi i checked the error log , `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function  is_user_logged_in()` , why is that so? I use it as described in wordpress codex.

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: I'm using Version 3.5.1

Comment: thanks , I found the solution , it seems I need to put the is_user_logged_in inside the function itself , i cannot wrap it around the add_action().

Comment: congrats i have also just found the real solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think as this function is in pluggable.php, that the function doesn't exist when the plugin is activated. This *should* mean that you just have to delay the loading of your logic.

```
function addbar(){
if(is_user_logged_in()){
    echo '<div id="cbar">';
    echo '</div>';
}
}

 add_action('wp_footer','addbar');
```